# Symfony Command Console chain using --no-interaction

Tags: symfony, console, command

I have several custom Symfony Console Commands which have interact and execute methods.

I would like to call one of these commands from another but am having trouble with the --no-interaction flag.

```
$command        = $this->getApplication()->find('app:create-user');
$bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutput();
$userInput      = new ArrayInput(
    array(
        'username'         => "d.vader",
        'password'         => "iAmY0urF4ther",
        'email'            => "d.vader@executor.com",
        'firstName'        => "Darth",
        'lastName'         => "Vader",
        '--no-interaction' => true
    )
);
$returnCode = $command->run($userInput, $bufferedOutput);
```

Doing so however causes a "Not enough arguments" error despite the fact that all the required arguments are set. Has anyone else tried to use the --no-interaction flag in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$userInput      = new ArrayInput(
    array(
        'command'          => 'app:create-user' // add this line
        'username'         => "d.vader",
        'password'         => "iAmY0urF4ther",
        'email'            => "d.vader@executor.com",
        'firstName'        => "Darth",
        'lastName'         => "Vader",
        '--no-interaction' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks @Roubi, your solution works on symfony 4. Did not find anything about setInteractive in [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/console/calling_commands.html)